# Android, Stop overlapping listview items by the page footer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my Java android application I use a listview to display information loading from the SQLite DB And a page footer also there in this page.

The problem is When there are more items loaded to the listview and need to scroll, since footer appears in the bottom of the page, the footer covers the the last item in the listview.

Simply I want to stop overlapping listview items by the footer.

Can any one help me achieve this please. Thanks inadvance.

Edits

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"    
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/companylistView"
              android:listSelector="@drawable/item_focus_bkg">
              </ListView>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
        <TextView android:text="Footer Text" 
                  android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:textColor="#000000" >
                  </TextView>       
    </LinearLayout>       


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the XML layout so that i can help you better

Comment: Hi Paresh, I added the XML layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your requirement(And as you haven't posted XML layout here that you have tried so far), i assume and can suggest the following:

1. give bottom margin to your listview: `android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"`
2. If you are using RelativeLayout then just give listview as `android:layout_above="@+id/footer"`

I suggest to you go with 2nd option.

### Update:

Based on the XML you have posted, try this correct XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"    
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:id="@+id/companylistView"
              android:layout_above="@+id/textView1">
    </ListView>

    <TextView 
        android:text="Footer Text" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </TextView>       
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Paresh, the problem is If I give android:layout_above="@+id/footer" for the list view, and if 1 or 2 items load to the listview  the list view just appearing on top of the footer. Overlaping is ok but it has a big space on top of the listview since list view placed in the below of the page.

Comment: @JibW check updated answer and correct your xml layout as same.

Comment: Hi paresh, Again when there are 1 or 2 elements(Less elements than the page height) in the listview, A space appearing on top of the listview. I need the list view to start from the top of the page and the footer to be appeared in the bottom of the page.

Comment: @JibW again check the updated xml layout, now if this is not working then post the snap of the problem that you are facing actually.

Comment: Hi Paresh Thank you very much it works fine, Yesterday I added android:layout_above="@+id/footer" for my previous layout. where I had gone wrong please?????

Comment: @JibW First, you have taken sub layout i.e. LinearLayout which is useless. Second, you haven't added android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in TextView. Third, add match_parent to ListView's height.

Answer (score 0):

You should use list footer like this:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);
list.addFooterView(footerView,null,false);
```

try this:

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"    
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/companylistView"
              android:listSelector="@drawable/item_focus_bkg" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"   
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <TextView 
            android:text="Footer Text" 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>       

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Vineet, In this way it creates a footer for the listview. When there are more items load to the listview, in the screen User can not see the footer since it appear in the end of the listview. What I want is to have a footer everytime on the screen even when no data, less data or too many data loaded to the listview.

Comment: When there are many items loaded to the listview and need to scroll the footer can not be seen in the page. when scroll until end of the list only its there. And also when 1 or 2 records in the listview rather than or appearing in the bottom of the page it appears in the end of the list view.

Comment: have you used the above code for footer view.Refer this:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: Hi Vineet, In this way we can add a footer to the listview. Not for the page. I need to add a footer to the page(always to appear in the bottom of the page even when many items are in listview or less items in the listview).

Comment: Why need to take sublayout if it is easily implemented using only one RelativeLayout?